# MapperParsingException [Analyzer [dbl_metaphone] not found for field [phonetic]]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-phonetic

I've an index on an Elasticsearch cluster, and I want to support phonetic matching.

This is my request:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/propertywebsites/_mapping/doc?pretty" -i -d '
{
"properties" : {
"phoneticbuilding" : {
"type" : "string",
"fields" : {
"phonetic" : {
"type" : "string",
"analyzer" : "dbl_metaphone"
}}}}
}
'
```

I received this error response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 116

{
  "error" : "MapperParsingException[Analyzer [dbl_metaphone] not found for field [phonetic]]",
  "status" : 400
}
```

Anyone has any idea about why the dbl_metaphone analyzer couldn't be recognized for phonetic fields?

My elasticsearch's version is `elasticsearch-1.7.2`

#### Update 1

I already have the analyzer as the following

```
PUT myIndexName/
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "dbl_metaphone": {
          "type": "phonetic",
          "encoder": "double_metaphone"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "dbl_metaphone": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": "dbl_metaphone"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Update 2

Querying this request

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/propertywebsites/_settings?pretty"
```

I get the following response:

```
{
  "propertywebsites" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1451838136296",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "1070299"
        },
        "uuid" : "KVOuKVgGRBudsSplownrgg",
        "analsis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "dbl_metaphone" : {
              "type" : "phonetic",
              "encoder" : "double_metaphone"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "dbl_metaphone" : {
              "filter" : "dbl_metaphone",
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your `myIndexName` and `propertywebsites` same or is this typo?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 yes they're the same, i just change it here in the question.

Comment: what does `GET propertywebsites/_settings` say?

Comment: You need to restart your cluster after adding that

Comment: @ChintanShah25 i updated my question to give you the result

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Yes I restarted already

Comment: this is the command i guess `bin/plugin install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic/2.7.0` , one in the link does not work. could that be an issue?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 the plugin is already installed, that's the message I get, so I removed the plugin, and installed it again, restart everything, but still getting the same exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99608/discussion-between-chintanshah25-and-william-kinaan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"dbl_metaphone" is a token filter and not an analyzer. You need to first install the Phonetic Analysis plug-in and then create a custom analyzer with it. Find more information at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phonetic-matching.html.

Comment: Please go through the documentation I mentioned completely. The plug-in only installs the token filter. You need to create a custom analyzer with it.

Comment: I've updated my question, isn't this the analyzer you're talking about ?

Comment: Does `GET propertywebsites/_mapping` list the analyzer "dbl_metaphone"?

Comment: No, It just gives me a list of the mapping for other fields that I've added before.

Comment: Did you restart all Elasticsearch nodes after installing the plugin on all nodes?

Comment: Yes I restarted everything already, maybe a problem in the phonetic version with my elasticsearch version

Comment: I don't know what was the problem, I just created a new index, and It's working